# Finding Top Twitter Friends Using Python

Tags: python, twitter, graph

What's the best way to find someone's top friends on twitter?

I'm trying to figure out a way to see who they interact with the most, but I am not sure what the best way is of doing this. Also, there are obvious things to check (is the username following that person, etc etc).

I imagine someone else has thought about this, so I am trying to get a little smarter on it. I am using Python to figure this out. Any help would be great.

Comment: How would you define "top friends"?

Comment: I dunno, that's a good question. I think people you interact with most. That's the only proxy you can use right? I'm trying to research, but that's the best starting point I've found. 

If that's the case, you might just look through a person's status messages, and count up everyone they've @'d. However, does that give you the best insight? What if people have close friends on twitter but don't @ them all the time, is there a way to get insight into that that I'm not thinking of?

Also, trying to find efficient ways to get a person's status history. Seems slow with the python api.

Answer (score 0):

I read a research paper about that. You can find it at http://arxiv.org/abs/1105.5170

The researchers where interested in studying the "strong relationships" in the twitter social graph and they are using metrics base on the number of message between the user (@... mentions).

I'm not a twitter user, but this looks like what you want to do. They add access to the whole social network, which is not available to everyone, but it could probably be adapted for a single user.